# The Why and the How of Creating a Watchdog in Cocoa/Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, macos, watchdog

Happy Monday to you all!

Here is my situation. Any assistance greatly appreciated!

I have created an executable that when installed gets placed in the Launch Agents folder of the machine. In theory it should run perpetually, collecting data every second. It can stop when the machine is asleep, but restart when the computer is reactivated.

Here is my problem: **sometimes the program just spontaneously stops**, usually after a couple of days of running. If one restarts the computer then the program restarts and again runs for awhile before the same problem occurs.

I have no idea the reason for this problem, but was told by a friend that I could create a 'watchdog' that every minute would check if my executable is running. If it is not, then the watchdog will restart the executable.

Any pointers as to how to do this? My apps are written in Objective-C and Cocoa and run on Macs.

Thanks so much!

---

**EDIT 1**

I will explain how the app works to the best of my ability. It is basically a collection of methods written in C and Objective C that queries information about the system every second:

- -bytes transmitted
- -keyboard activity-
- -mouse activity-
- -percentage of harddrive used up
- -process which has keyboard focus

...etc.

It does this using low level API's provided by the Apple Developer website. It writes the information to a file every second. Every hour the file is zipped up and a new file is created.

Please ask if more clarification is needed :)

---

**EDIT 2**

For those who are wondering, here is the plist file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
 <plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
     <key>Label</key>
     <string>com.Intel</string>
     <key>OnDemand</key>
     <true/>
     <key>ProgramArguments</key>
     <array>
         <string>/Library/LaunchAgents/Contents/Intel</string>
     </array>
     <key>RunAtLoad</key>
     <true/>
 </dict>
 </plist>
```

Thanks again....

---

Comment: You'll probably get better luck if you tell us how you're doing things right now.

Comment: @jer, Thanks for your interest. Not really sure what you want clarified though. My executable is a program that collects data like the number of bytes transmitted, every second. It is a daemon that is launched on startup because it is placed in the Launch Agents folder complete with plist file. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: What I'm asking for is you to outline your program, not that it exists, but how it's currently doing things since you're asking for alternatives, it's best we know how it's being done now.

Comment: @alexy13, I wouldn't know what part of the code to post because I have no idea where the problem is. If launchd starts the program and it runs for a few days and then stops, how can I tell where in the code is the problem? Frankly I feel as if I'm missing something in how Apple treats Launch Agents.

Comment: Post the plist file. That's the single most important aspect controlling any launchd agents!

Comment: @Yuji, please check my 2nd edit. Thanks for your interest :)

Comment: Eric Brotto: You haven't fully specified an identifier for your agent; you stopped at “com.intel”, without putting at least a third component after it. Also, what kind of path is “/Library/LaunchAgents/Contents/Intel”? Did you really install your agent executable in a Contents folder in the LaunchAgents folder? The LaunchAgents folder should contain nothing but launch agent plists; depending on the architecture of your program, you should put it either inside of a prefpane or in an application in /Applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use launchd as your watchdog. Simply add the following key-value pair to your launchd plist file:

```
 <key>KeepAlive</key>
 <true/>
```

This will ensure that your process will be relaunched if it crashes or otherwise terminates. (It won't help if your process hangs, however.) For complete documentation on KeepAlive and other launchd keys, run "man launchd.plist" in Terminal.