# Why does a Daemon randomly stop?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, macos, daemon

This is sort of related to a [previous, yet so far unsuccessful question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650003/the-why-and-the-how-of-creating-a-watchdog-in-cocoa-objective-c). I have a daemon that is placed in the LaunchAgents folder (on Mac) and it should run perpetually in the background, but after a couple of days it just stops for no apparent reason. I have no idea why and thus my question:

**What are the reasons that a daemon might randomly stop?**

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Eiko, Good point, but I don't see anything in the crash logs. Do you know of any other way I could verify if it is crashing? And if so, why it is crashing? Thanks :)

Comment: Not sure if something gets logged to the console / system logs. Maybe try with a little daemon that you make crash early.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Daemon is just a long lasting (forked) process. The reason a Daemon crashes is the same any other program crashes:

- attempting to read or write memory
  that is not allocated for reading or
  writing by that application
  (segmentation fault) or x86 specific
  (general protection fault)
- attempting to execute privileged or
  invalid instructions
- attempting to perform I/O operations
  on hardware devices to which it does
  not have permission to access
- passing invalid arguments to system
  calls
- attempting to access other system
  resources to which the application
  does not have permission to access
  (bus error)
- attempting to execute machine
  instructions with bad arguments
  (depending on CPU architecture):
  divide by zero, operations on denorms
  or NaN values, memory access to
  unaligned addresses, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a LaunchAgent, it runs as part of your login session, and hence will be killed if you log out.

On the other hand, if it's dying before you log out, and you can't find/fix whatever is causing it to crash/exit, or you can tell launchd to automatically restart it by adding

```
<key>KeepAlive</key>
</true>
```

to its .plist